# Crawl a whole website with selenium in python recursive

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler

I'm new in python and i try to crawl a whole website recursive with selenium.
I would like to do this with selenium because i want get all cookies which the website is used. I know that other tools can crawl a website easier and faster but other tools can't give me all cookies (first and third party).

Here my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os, shutil


url = "http://example.com/"
links = set()


def crawl(start_link):
    driver.get(start_link)
    elements = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
    urls_to_visit = set()

    for el in elements:
        urls_to_visit.add(el.get_attribute('href'))

    for el in urls_to_visit:
        if url in el:
            if el not in links:
                links.add(el)
                crawl(el)
            else:
                return


dir_name = "userdir"
if os.path.isdir(dir_name):
    shutil.rmtree(dir_name)
co = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
co.add_argument("--user-data-dir=userdir")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = co)
crawl(url)
print(links)
driver.close();
```

My problem is that the crawl function not open all pages from the website apparently. On some websites i can navigate to pages by hand that the function not reached. Why?

Comment: is your url public?

Comment: No sorry. For example you can use [this website](https://www.miss-thrifty.co.uk/). If you scroll to the bottom of the page you can see a link to older posts and when you click this link you get another page with blogposts and on this page is a [link to a blogpost](https://www.miss-thrifty.co.uk/the-financial-admin-diet-little-often/) which is not in my crawler links set for example.

Comment: I don't know any python, but seems like you need to call crawl(el) for each link found.  Right now it calls it for the first link you haven't yet visitted... then urls_to_visit is getting blasted... probably need to define that outside of the function that runs the driver.get()... keep a list of grabbed URLs, and one of visitted.

Comment: btw, assuming that the recursion is working here, the driver is a single browser instance.  That won't be multiple... (and probably don't want it to be cause that would open a ton of browsers...).

Comment: now that I think on it more, I think what is happening is you are generating a whole bunch of driver calls which are not happening in the order you want.  Selenium will wait for pageready after the get, and during that time you're making more and more calls in a recursive loop.  I think you need to make all Selenium calls outside of that recursion.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I have noticed while using webdriver is that it needs time to load the page, the elements are not instantly available just like in a regular browser.

You may want to add some delays, or a loop to check for some type of footer to indicate that the page is loaded and you can start crawling.